# Mockito 3.4.0 Static Mocking Exception

Tags: android, mockito, mockito-kotlin

I am getting the following exception when trying to mock the static method.

> For SettingsUtility, static mocking is already registered in the
> current thread To create a new mock, the existing static mock
> registration must be deregistered

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    mockStatic(SettingsUtility::class.java) {
        `when` { SettingsUtility.method(app) }.thenReturn { "" }}
}
```

Answer (score 94):

The returned object's MockedStatic.close() method must be called upon completing the test or the mock will remain active on the current thread.

I am not sure if it is the same as how its done in Java. Hope this Java code snippet helps

```
private static MockedStatic<SettingsUtility> mockedSettings;

@BeforeAll
public static void init() {
    mockedSettings = mockStatic(SettingsUtility.class);
}

@AfterAll
public static void close() {
    mockedSettings.close();
}
```

Comment: good one, for me the tags if for each test, but it's the same. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 32):

Try doing this way, you will not get this error. It worked for me.

```
try(MockedStatic mocked = mockStatic(SettingsUtility.class)) {
        mocked.when(SettingsUtility::method).thenReturn("whatever you want");
    }
```

Comment: For me one Testclass gave some really good insight, how to use the new statickMock-Feature:
[StaticMockTest.java](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/4767db122f95e5302ad6a60a6efaa69f9d7e6cb1/subprojects/inline/src/test/java/org/mockitoinline/StaticMockTest.java) (it's quite important to use the try-Block/call close).

Comment: very helpful comment!

Comment: Saved me so much time!

Comment: so you need to close them explicitly or auto-close it, ok.

Comment: Hiding the error is not a good idea. You better close the mock in the @After

Answer (score 19):

Building on @Sudha 's answer.
in Java you can use @BeforeClass and @AfterClass

```
private static MockedStatic<SettingsUtility> mockedSettings;

@BeforeClass
public static void init() {
    mockedSettings = mockStatic(mockedSettings.class);
}

@AfterClass
public static void close() {
    mockedSettings.close();
}
```

Comment: `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` are JUnit 4 constructs. JUnit 5 in java is what @sudha-chinnappa was showing.

Comment: @gaoagong correct, above annotation works on Junit 4. In junit5 it should be -BeforeAll and -AfterAll

Answer (score 12):

Mockito Inline works differently than the Mockito hence the failure. So what needs to be done is initialise and close the mocks explicitly.

You need to initialise the mockedStatic for your class

```
private MockedStatic<YourClassWithStaticMethod> mockedStatic;
```

Then add below code in BeforeEach and AfterEach

```
@BeforeEach
  public void init() {
    mockedStatic = mockStatic(YourClassWithStaticMethod.class);
  }

@AfterEach
  public void cleanup() {
    mockedStatic.close();
  }
```

And now you can set the mocked expectations.

```
mockedStatic.when(YourClassWithStaticMethod::staticMethodToMock).thenReturn(yourReturnedMockedObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried below and worked for me.

```
MockedStatic mockedStatic = mockStatic(SettingsUtility.class)
mocked.when(SettingsUtility::method).thenReturn("any thing");
...........
//do all stuf
```

and at last close the mock

```
mockedStatic.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use MockedStatic in function context inside try() that auto-closes it rather than using it as private static class variable.  Using it at a class level variable will result into these sort of error even if you close them in AfterAll or AfterEach.

Example -

try (
MockedStatic mockedYourClassStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(YourClass.class)
) { ... }

Also you can refer to this -

https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/4767db122f95e5302ad6a60a6efaa69f9d7e6cb1/subprojects/inline/src/test/java/org/mockitoinline/StaticMockTest.java

Answer (score 0):

@sudha-chinnappa answer is the one.
Use:

```
@AfterAll
public static void close() {
  mockedSettings.close();
```

}

To close the static mocking

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34761131)